# Running multiple post requests in nodejs using for loop not working

Tags: node.js, async-await, http-post, jwt, rest

this is the signup route where the request is called

```
  User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), 
    req.body.password, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({err: err});
    }
    else {
      if(req.body.admin) {
        user.admin = req.body.admin;
      }
      if(req.body.hostel) {
        user.hostel = req.body.hostel;
      }
      user.save((err, user) => {
        if(err) {
          res.statusCode = 500; 
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.json({err: err});
          return;
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.json({success: true, status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

this snippet is from where the request is called..
I called the axios post inside a for loop to register multiple users from a csv file

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
var axios = require('axios');
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        //console.log(results);
       for(var i = 10; i <= 20; i++) {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/signup', 
        {
            password: results[i].DOB, 
            username: results[i].Sid,
            hostel: '5f37923011855135682d1ae8'
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(`Status: ${res.status}`);
            console.log('Body: ', res.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
       }

            
    });
```

when posting single data returns a success else server generates error code 500

Comment: You return code 500 when create user failure `res.statusCode = 500; `, can you show error message?

Comment: response: {
    status: 500,
    statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
    headers: {
      'x-powered-by': 'Express',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '99',
      etag: 'W/"63-x1XdFOOps5o4GVYv4RC9A0nJwI4"',
      date: 'Fri, 28 Aug 2020 10:59:44 GMT',
      connection: 'close'
    }